# how to mimic the js decodeURIComponent in c++?

Tags: c++, encoding, uri

i have string (uri) that i need to decode in c++ , its have to be as js decodeURIComponent function 
so that this string :

```
http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBuv4KHE_CDlCPV&w=130&h=130&url=http00253A00252F00252Fi1.ytimg.com00252Fvi00252F8dWcLkK62lM00252Fhqdefault.jpg
```

will look like this :

```
http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/8dWcLkK62lM/hqdefault.jpg
```

is there some mini class that deal with all uri encoding in c++ ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a small cross platform library to do this, Consider using **[uriparser](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net)**. BSD license and no external dependencies

Comment: befor i look in the documents , its looks good , it will do the job ?

Answer (score 1):

check out http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/

it's a C library, so no problem to use it under C++

Crossplatform Windows,Linux,etc. Under linux you can install it with apt-get.

Comment: yeah i see it but hell .. i dont understand how i decode the uri from the examples and sources

Comment: i just can't understand how to use it ...can some one help ?